# Multiple item restore not working in laravel 8 using softdeletes

Tags: laravel

```
 public function trashRestore(Request $req){
    $id = $req->id;
    switch($req->action){
        case 'restoreAll':
          
            $data=Product::withTrashed()->whereIn('id',$id)->restore();
            return redirect()->route('get.products')->with('success','Selected all products has restored');
            break;

        case 'deleteAll':
            $multiple_resotre= Product::onlyTrashed()->whereIn('id',$id)->forceDelete();
            return redirect()->route('get.products')->with('success','Selected all products has deleted');
                break;
       

 }
}
```

count function displaying there are 5 trash item but it's not restoring using withTrashed()method.
I had tried with onlyTrashed() too.

Comment: Is `$id` an array or single id?

Comment: It's an array  .

Comment: Allright, what do you get if you run `Product::withTrashed()->whereIn('id',$id)->get()` ? You should at least get the products that you mean to restore. Do you have any custom scopes on product?

Comment: I get an empty array. But there are 5 trash item as a object. I converted it to an array so that my req id compare with it .

Comment: Does your array of `ids` contain an `id` that is trashed?

Comment: yes array has id and array of ids output is like this {"11":"on","8":"on","6":"on"}

Comment: Ok, maybe thats your problem. can you manually do `$ids = [11,8,6]`  before the query? I think you have a formatting issue.

Comment: I fix this issue , The problem was in blade file . I didn't give any value of the input tag where from I snatching the id.